# Hibernate error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I did a small example program to insert data to a MySQL database table using java Hibernate. Every thing went fine & I got the result

"INFO: schema update complete
Hibernate: insert into items (itemcode, itemdiscription, itemprice, itemId) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)"

My mapping file & config file are OK.
But when I'm running the query in command prompt to fetch updated values it doesn't show entered values by my java pojo class.
Why is that???
Please consider I have used netbeans 7.1 for this.

Mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"     "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="firsthibernetapp.Item" table="items">
              <id name="iid" type="int" column="itemId" >
                 <generator class="assigned"/>
              </id>
              <property name="icode">
                    <column name="itemcode"/>
              </property>
              <property name="idiscription">
                     <column name="itemdiscription"/>
              </property>
              <property name="iprice">
                     <column name="itemprice"/>
              </property>
          </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernet.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD     3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306      /combo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">********</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  <mapping resource="hibernate.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Code:

```
package firsthibernetapp;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class FirstHibernetApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Session session = null;
    try{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = 
                 new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session =sessionFactory.openSession();
        Item item = new Item();
        System.out.println("Inserting Record");
        item.setIid(5);
        item.setIcode("FX00010");
        item.setIdiscription("Apple");
        item.setIprice(10);
        session.save(item);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        session.flush();
        session.close();
     }
  }
}
```

`

Comment: What do you mean with "command line"? Which query are you using? What is `select * from items` show?

Comment: I typed "SELECT * FROM items;"
(items is my database table). This only shows data entered using command line.

Comment: You must show the (relevant) code... Looks like you did not properly commit your transaction

Comment: I have posted some codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add these lines..
session =sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); //new line
Item item = new Item();



session.save(item);
 System.out.println("Done");
 tx.commit(); //new line
 }catch(Exception e){
...
```

Comment: Now it shows this error::::::......
"org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction cannot be cast to javax.transaction.Transaction"

Comment: My database variables except Id & price are varchar s but in my java class I declared those as private String s.

Comment: you should either import org.hibernate.*; in your program or to be very sure, you can change the line to 

org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

Comment: OK! cool....Thanks user331225.... I did a small change to your code & now it is working.... I stated above what I did....
:)